# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, pointers, callback

I'm making a small game for a microboard. It's an Arkanoid game. I'm trying to implement a callback in this way:

```
typedef void    (*TPFN_BEHAVIOUR)(int block_number); 

typedef struct
  {
      int square_number;
      int initial_x;
      int initial_y;
      int final_x;
      int final_y;
      TPFN_BEHAVIOUR behaviour;
}Square;

Square  block[150];
```

Then I do:

```
block[i].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife;
```

where app_Detect_Collision_SendLife is

```
void app_DetectCollision_SendLife(int i){

    int initial_x = block[i].final_x - block[i].initial_x - 5;
    int initial_y = block[i].final_y;
    services_Screen_Draw(heart, initial_x, initial_y, 10, 9);
}
```

I'm getting the error shown in the title in the following line:

```
 block[special_block].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife;
```

Comment: could you post entire code. [what is `special_block`?]

Comment: Where in the code is `app_DetectCollision_SendLife`declared? Is it before the line ` block[special_block].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife;`?

Comment: It's just an integer. A way to iterate over the structure array. I can't post all the code because it's huge long. Just ask me what you need and I'll explain to you.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's before or after because they're in different source files

Comment: is block in scope where its being referenced with `block[special_block].behaviour`

Comment: Well your file with the line `block[special_block].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife;` doesn not know what the name `app_DetectCollision_SendLife` means. So include the function prototype of the header file.

Comment: The function prototype is already included in the header file and not working

Comment: One possibility is that the scope where `block[special_block].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife;` occurs has an incorrect declaration of `block` that is not an array.  Check that it isn't something like `Square block;`

Comment: Solved!! Thanks to all of you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the scope where block[special_block].behaviour = app_DetectCollision_SendLife; occurs has an incorrect declaration of block that is not an array. Check that it isn't something like Square block;

THANKS TO

Mark Plotnick

Answer (score 0):

Compiles on my system. Must be `blocks` is not known when you use it. If it's located in a different file, use extern to have the compiler know it.

In C file where blocks is defined:

```
Square  block[150];
```

In C file where blocks is used (or in header file):

```
extern Square  block[150];
```

Comment: Block is defined as extern in all the files it's needed. The error seems to be something related with pointers :/

Comment: This is the error I got when block wasn't defined. Try calling sizeof(block) and see what happens. Also try giving this array a more unique name, it might collide with something.